# Disable multiple buttons

Tags: swift3

I am learning swift3 and decided to try a tictactoe game. I am trying to disable all the buttons once the game is over. I try to do

```
sender.isEnabled = false
```

but this gives me an error. Is there a way to disable all buttons, other than making outlet for individual buttons and disabling them one by one?
below is my code

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let gamePosition = sender.tag - 1

    if gamePlay == true {

        if gameState[gamePosition] == 0 {

            if activePlayer == 1 {

                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "nought.png"), for: [])

                gameState[gamePosition] = activePlayer

                activePlayer = 2


            } else {

                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: [])

                gameState[gamePosition] = activePlayer

                activePlayer = 1

            }

        }

    }


    for combination in winningCombination {

        if gameState[combination[0]] != 0 && gameState[combination[0]] == gameState[combination[1]] && gameState[combination[1]] == gameState[combination[2]] {

            gamePlay = false

            resultLabel.isHidden = false
            playAgainButton.isHidden = false

            if gameState[combination[0]] == 1 {

                resultLabel.text = ("noughts have won")

            } else {

                resultLabel.text = (" crosses won")

            }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is "cannot assign to property: 'sender' is a 'let' constant

Comment: I can not reproduce this using `sender.isEnabled = false`. Please post (only) the relevant code where you are using `sender.isEnabled = false`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason (I assume a bug) dragging `UIButton` Actions sets `AnyObject` instead of `UIButton` as sender type by default.

Replace:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: AnyObject) {
```

with:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

Answer (score 0):

changing `AnyObject` to `UIButton` fixed the error I was getting.
To disable all button once the game was over, I did this (not sure if its the best way)

```
for i in 1..<10 {
    if let Button = view.viewWithTag(i) as? UIButton{
        Button.isEnabled = false
        }
```